# This code works fine in Chrome, Firefox but not in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I'm trying to make a jquery tooltip that appears when a user mouses over a link. In my case the link is using display:block style so that it covers a large area. It works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox but in Internet Explorer it doesn't work at all. The tooltip doesn't show, the browsers own tooltip shows etc... IE!!!!

http://pastebin.com/1kBaMujV

Any ideas? Got to love internet explorer...

Comment: Please post the code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of IE you are using? In IE 8 it is fine.

Comment: a few months ago i downloaded a beta of IE 9.

Comment: It is something to do with the CSS you are using, if I found it I'll update here. Why are you developing your own tooltip, there are many tooltip plugins already available out there? I'm using this one in my project http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/

Comment: I wasn't able to find one that a) will follow the mouse and b) can target a link and use the title attribute of the link as content inside the tooltip. In Chrome is just perfect, in Firefox it works but if someone clicks on the link then clicking back button in browser, the tooltip wont move and a copy of it appears in an area of the page where it shouldnt be.

Comment: I'll strongly suggest you to use a already available solution rather than going for writing a completely new one yourself.

Comment: Ok. Well initially i wanted to use this one: http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html However i'm not sure how to get it to follow the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

Ok well i took your advice and went for a pre existing one using jQueryTools from flowplayer. This is the result:

http://pastebin.com/gxSQx64B

Works great in chrome, firefox and internet explorer. I guess it is best to use one that is mature. The only thing that still annoys me is in firefox if you click on the link then click the browser back button, the tooltip is statically displayed over the link area until you move the mouse back over the link area. This doesn't happen with the other browsers.